# aws api gateway model design for dynamic key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I am designing an AWS API gateway request model. In my case the input key will change dynamically like below

```
[
  {
    "losAngeles": {
      "weatherInCelcius": 84.5
    }
  },
  {
    "sanFrancisco": {
      "weatherInCelcius": 80
    }
  }
]
```

Here the city name(losAngeles,sanFrancisco) will change dynamically

can anyone help me to create API model JSON for this dynamically changing key

I tried like below

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "weather",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "TBD": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json-schema [draft-04 has a `patternProperties` keyword](https://json-schema.org/draft-04/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.4.4) that can be used here. Specifically, you can change your example into this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "weather",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

The `".*"` defines that any name for a property is allowed. If you have more specific constraints, you can change that RegEx accordingly.